# Why VCorpus() from tm package in R yields unreasonably large size of object?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

The size of 'corpus' object created using 'tm' package in R was inflated  disproportionately compared to original textVector object. Is there a way to compress the 'corpus' size? The text vector created from data.frame had 18 million rows.

```
textVector <-
sapply(df, as.character)) #df contains one 'character' column with 18M rows
system.time(corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(textVector)))
object.size(textVector) # 601 MB
object.size(corpus)     #69.9GB
```

Any hint is appreciated. Thank you.

```
System info 

 [1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"; $version.string [1] "R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)"
   $Session info: [1] tm_0.6-2
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory size of the corpus object is expected because you have 18 M rows. When you are creating a virtual text document for each row of the `df` it is expected to be of this large size(6.9 GB).  Below is a simplified example. When you `inspect` the corpus you can see that each vector is saved as separate collection of documents containing text information.

`Vcorpus` is generally used to create a volatile object when we handle multiple files for text processing. Your goal is unclear on why you are creating corpus for each row. If you could share more details on what you are trying to do, I am sure someone else could give you more insight on how to use the `VCorpus`.

```
x <- c("hello","hi","What does Corups do ?")
df <- as.data.frame(x)
textVector <-
  sapply(df, as.character)
system.time(corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(textVector)))
object.size(textVector)
object.size(corpus)
inspect(corpus)
```

Comment: My goal here is to create an attribute profile of 18M customers (identifier) based on their activity footprints which is stored as a text data in a column. I was trying to use 'tm' package for cleaning up the data in order to create customer-word matrix for further modeling down the road. I thought treating each row as a separate document would help me to clean up the text using functions in tm pakage. I am willing to consider any other efficient option in R for cleaning up the text. Thanks.

Comment: I am now looking into 'stringr' and 'stringi' package for cleaning up texts and  "slam" package for customer-word matrix. "slam" package looks very fast. Will update if this alternative is efficient in processing big data of this size. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at quanteda to create the dtm directly